# fire ngOnChanges on component model property

Tags: angular

On my template I have this line of code:

```
<input name="distanceA" id="distanceA" type="number" [(ngModel)]="distanceA"/> {{distanceA}} meter
```

In it's component.ts file I have this:

```
distanceA: number;
```

and further on this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if (changes["distanceA"] ) {
       alert(changes["distanceA"].currentValue);
    }
    if (changes["distanceB"] ) {
       alert(changes["distanceB"].currentValue);
    }
}
```

However the ngOnChanges event doesn't fire when typing in the inputbox. What's the reason for this? How can I make this work? The binding itself works as I see what I type in the inputbox showing up on the page with {{distanceA}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it with (keypress) event.

Short example.

```
<input placeholder="0-99999" minlength="1" maxlength="5" name="areaCode" [(ngModel)]="number" (keypress)="validateNumber($event)" required>

validateNumber(event): boolean {
    return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's as designed. `ngOnChanges` isn't called when a property is modified, it's called when a bound value (bound with `[distanceA]="propFromParent"`) is changed that causes the `@Input()` of the child component to be changed.

Just change your property to a getter/setter like

```ts
_distanceA: number;
get distanceA() { return this._distanceA; }
set distanceA(val:number) { 
  this._distanceA = val; 
  alert(val);
}
```